# POST Request to Proxy Service WSO2

Tags: post, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I am sending a post request to proxy service but its giving error ... how can i resove this one

```
[2012-06-15 12:24:27,656]  INFO - BuilderUtil OMException in getSOAPBuilder
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:140)
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.getSOAPBuilder(BuilderUtil.java:688)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:197)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:145)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:409)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:173)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:686)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2134)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2040)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1069)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 13 more
[2012-06-15 12:24:27,675]  INFO - BuilderUtil Remaining input stream :[]
[2012-06-15 12:24:27,675] ERROR - ServerWorker Error processing POST request 
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:409)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:173)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:140)
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.getSOAPBuilder(BuilderUtil.java:688)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:197)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:145)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:686)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2134)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2040)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1069)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 13 more
```

my proxy cinfiguration is :

```
<proxy name="stripe" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
        <target>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="https://api.stripe.com/v1"/>
            </endpoint>
            <inSequence>
                <log level="full" separator="SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSs">
                    <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="post"/>
                </log>
                <send/>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <log level="full" separator=", ooooooooooo"/>
                <send/>
            </outSequence>
        </target>
    </proxy>
```

Curl command to execute the request:

```
curl https://localhost:8243/services/stripe/charges/ch_iQs4noWTm7J5Kk/refund  -u Ixj3FHIiQSFWrzb4VNSxoThKVk3IXpBF --insecure -X POST
```

I am not getting the exact reason for dis error

Comment: Hi how did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What is the content type of the POST request. This error happens when you don't have the message fomatter and builder for the content type used.

Comment: Ok. Then in the axis2.xml, please check whether you have JSON Builders and formatters for the content type application/json.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 7 days on this bug. There are many different answers to this bug.

It's happened when your web service return to wso proxy empty body or incorrect content-length or something else (there are many things).

But in my case the problem was that my webservice on my route '/' (POST method) return 400 code if content-length equal 0. I think wso2 proxy by first step send some data to my webservice with zero content-length header or without this header and my webservice just "block" this and return 400 code.